# How to LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql with first col being Auto Increment?

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently, We have a table similar to this:

```
---------------------
ID | AField | BField|
---------------------
```

The ID is Auto Increment

How do I create a CSV that can let the database auto populate the ID field with auto increment number?

We've tried the following CSV but it doesn't work:

```
afieldvalue, bfieldvalue (With Column definition but still doesn't work)
0,afieldvalue,bfieldvalue 
NULL,afieldvalue,bfieldvalue
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The best thing to do is just include the 2 non-auto-increment columns in the CSV, and then explicitly set the ID column to NULL in the load data infile statement.

Something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(AField, BField)
SET ID = NULL;
```

Comment: Use `(your_table.AField, your_table.BField)` instead if your CSV has the same column names.

Comment: @Thilo LOAD DATA INFILE does not read column names from the CSV. That's why you must set the columns to the exact order of the CSV column data.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that if the data has been exported including the `ID` column it can be import with ... `(@UnusedVariable,AField,BField)`

Answer (score 7):

you can "omit" ID field in data row by placing delimiter sign in the beginning of a row, like this (for table schema `ID,AField,BField`):

```
,afieldvalue,bfieldvalue
...
```

SQL engine will assign `NULL` to `ID` field while reading such csv file

Comment: What worked for me was to provide "NULL" or "\N" (note the capital N) in the CSV file for the auto increment field. 
 Providing a blank value resulted in "ErrorCode: 1366 Warning: Incorrect integer value: '' for column \`database\`.\`table\`.\`the_id_column\`".  10.5.16-MariaDB on an InnoDB table.

Answer (score 4):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/data.csv'
INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
(AField, BField);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use NULL as the value in the csv file for the ID field.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` in CSV file is read as a STRING in MySQL. If you want to have null values in a MySQL column instead use `\N` in place of `NULL. This will fix the issue and you will get the required result.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked - this worked for my ID column that is an INT

Comment: FYI using the string `NULL` did work for me today, for an `int` auto increment primary key field, but to my surprise the string `\N` also worked, but it has to be uppercase `N`, `\n` did not work.

Comment: The ```sed``` command to replace emtpy values with ```\N```
```sed  's/,,/,\\N,/g; s/,,/,\\N,/g; s/,$/,\\N/g;'```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a small number of columns, you can just name them:
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt' INTO TABLE mytable (AField);` (assuming only ID & AField)

Answer (score -1):

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

That was the key to success for me when using a text file

Comment: love it when you get a down vote without a comment lol.  I am sure others will also need to terminate the line as I mentioned in order to get the solution to work, if you are going to downvote, explain why so others can comprehend / learn from the wisdom of your insight.

Comment: Doesn't seem to explain how to skip the ID field; nor does it explain what it does. What if your lines *aren't* terminated by `\r\n`?

Comment: Clearly the question was changed or merged, my answer was in relation to issues with terminating a line to have separate results in the document show line by line, it must have been expanded to include sql info later.

Comment: I don't see anything in the edit history, but it is from a while ago, and I think not everything was preserved.