# load data infile mysql null value entry error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a text file into an existing table by issuing the following command

```
load data infile "test.txt" into table m_c;
```

The table has 5 columns: id, title, official, genre and platform
where the id is the primary key with auto_increment set.

The file was added to the table, but the content was not. Instead i got NULL as values for all columns.

I really need to know why!

Comment: It would be great if you could add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`, as well as a few rows from file.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach here you have the print screen [IMG]http://i48.tinypic.com/11ky2jk.png[/IMG]

Comment: Based on the shot you have provided, I would advise you use `varchar` unless those fields will be the defined length of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
  INTO TABLE m_c
  (title, genre, platform, official)
SET gameid = NULL;
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment)

Also, how is your file formatted? Tab delimited? CSV? You may need file or line terminators.

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Strangely enough it added the last entry from the file, the rest were null

Comment: I just want to confirm, you have 6 fields and are trying to insert into 5 fields?

Comment: no the P, X, W are one but I guess the commas need to be removed

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Please reply if you need further direction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an ID field in your text file, the system will automatically give you a new id for each row you insert.

Comment: I don't know about that - because I don't know what Ids you have in the text. But I'm commenting to Ryan E that his answer does not automatically apply here.