# MySQL Load Data Infile auto incremented ID value

Tags: mysql, indexing, auto-increment, load-data-infile

I want to insert an ID column to my table and get data of this table from a text file.
For example my text file is like that:

```
12    1212    4989    121
121   23      123     110
789   99      234     544
...
```

and it has approximately 20M rows. I want to insert this data to a table and include an auto incremented ID value column for it. I will use "Load data infile", but I want to create my table as indicated below:

```
id    a     b       c       d
---   ---   ---     ---     ---  
1    12    1212    4989    121
2    121   23      123     110
3    789   99      234     544
...
```

How can I create this kind of table using mysql (workbench)

Answer (score 19):

first, create table with column ID has auto increment property:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     a INT NULL,
     b INT NULL,
     c INT NULL,
     d INT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

then you should load data into table with load data infile by giving column names:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/DATA/mydata.txt'
INTO TABLE test.mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(a, b, c, d) SET ID = NULL;
```

see : [How to LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql with first col being Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment)

Comment: it was common sense to create table first.and also the "load infile" has only 4 columns i.e.autoincrement column is not going to fill

Comment: If any of your field names include periods, you'll need to surround them with backticks.

Comment: it is incremented but it is not an order.and how can i make a order

Answer (score 0):

this can do for u..

```
     load data local infile 'data.csv' into table tbl fields terminated by ','
     enclosed by '"'
     fields terminated by '\t'
     lines terminated by '\n'
     (a,b,c,d)
```

for more reference see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)