# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have tried the suggestion in the question below but I still have syntax errors.

[How to LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql with first col being Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment)

```
create table db.test
(ai_id int(11) auto_increment primary key,
field varchar(5))

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\nick\\Desktop\\test\\book1.csv' 
INTO TABLE db.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(field)
SET ai_id = NULL
IGNORE 1 lines;
```

I am having trouble reconciling this seemingly very simple syntax error, any assistance greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
error code: 1064: You have error in SQL syntax; check syntax around 'ignore 1 lines' line 8.

datasource is a csv with one column "field" with five rows "one"-"five"(all five rows are characters not int)

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data.It seems to me the varchar size might be too small.Also what are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is correct, I tested its working(in MySQL 5.6). please verify your input file.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. It appears the order of commands is what threw it off.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\nshatz\\Desktop\\test\\book1.csv' 
INTO TABLE db.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 lines
(field);
```