# with mysql load data infile I get "incorrect integer value"

Tags: mysql

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'thefile.csv' 
INTO TABLE word 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET id = NULL;
```

I am a bit lost of what to do here, I thought this query would work but it doesn't. I get the error about id, which is why I thought set id = NULL would make it good but no. The point of my id row (which is AUTO_INCREMENT) is that I don't need to specify the ID. so.. ehm. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
```

My CSV file content:

```
id;meaning;japanese;kanji;kana;romaji;visible;featured;image;image_author;imgauthor_link;extra
;pants;パンツ;;パンツ;pantsu;;;;;;
```

Comment: Your question looks a lot like this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment

Comment: Thanks that seems very helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify all column names except the id column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'thefile.csv' 
INTO TABLE word 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1,col2,col3);
```

I assumed your table has  (id,col1,col2,col3) columns.

Comment: @Emil can you show which documentation and which part of it say that? Did you test my answer and it did not work?  I previously tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a two step load:

1) Load the data into a table;

2) Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` to get your data in your table

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE baseData (
    All your column definitions, but not your id column
);

INSERT INTO (all your columns except the id column) SELECT * FROM baseData;
```

Alternative option:

> Create your table with the id as last column, then the loading with LOAD DATA INFILE works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred in other columns, not the primary key.

The solution was to replace any null values with \N instead of leaving them as ,, .

```
cat example.csv
1,foobar,1,0,1
2,barfoo,,,
3,foofoo,,,
```

You can use sed to replace empty values with \N null values.

```
cat example.csv | sed   -e ':a' -e 's/,,/,\\N,/g;  s/,$/,\\N/g; ta'
1,foobar,1,0,1
2,barfoo,\N,\N,\N
3,foofoo,\N,\N,\N
```

Note: use \N not \n.