# How to auto add column by using SQL-load data into table?

Tags: mysql, sql, file, csv, import

The scenario is that I have a .csv file which columns are

> {Name,Number,Point}

(please think this a student grade sheet)

I used LOAD DATA INFILE but my database schema is

> {Class,Name,Number,Point}

So every record will always got 1 column differences.

Can I ONLY use "SQL" code to auto set {Class}=304?

(not edit the .csv file itself or change db schema)

Thanks a lot !! (forgiving bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you always want the {Class} to be = 304 you can just set 304 as a default for that column?

```
alter table "TABLE" alter column Class set default 304;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are loading the data using [`load data infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

One simple method is to load the data and use `set`:

```
load data infile . . . 
   into . . .
   (name, number, point)
       set class = 304;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I described the question too ambiguous. 
Here is the answer I actually need.

[How to LOAD DATA INFILE in mysql with first col being Auto Increment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017032/how-to-load-data-infile-in-mysql-with-first-col-being-auto-increment)